# Private inheritance from vector, exposing equality operator

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, vector

I need a vector which stores elements in sorted order (I need constant-time random access too, so not `std::set`). I am trying to implement that by privately inheriting `std::vector`.

```
template <typename T, typename Tcomp = less<T> >
class SortedVector : private vector<T> {

    Tcomp _comparator;


public:
    using vector<T>::operator[];
    using vector<T>::operator==;
    using vector<T>::size;
```

I have a couple of questions:

1. Is it a bad idea to inherit `std::vector` privately?
2. I get the following error:

   > SortedVector.h:26:30: error: no members matching ‘`std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::operator==`’ in ‘`class std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >`’

Any advice?

Comment: Do you really *need* `operator==` on a vector? If so it's not difficult to write your own.

Comment: I do need it, and yes, it's not that difficult, but I couldn't figure out why I got that error.

Comment: For std::vector, `operator==()` is a non-member function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as it's private inheritance, it's ok, it's mostly a less verbose composition here.

For the `==` operator, you can't use `std::vector::operator==` cause there is none, it is defined as a free function, so you will have to declare one yourself if you need it

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little bit ugly way, but it does work.

```cpp
inline bool operator==(const SortedVector& right) const {
    return static_cast<vector<T>>(*this) == right;
}
```